# efficiently copy h5py attributes to python dict in one step

Tags: dictionary, attr, h5py

is there a fast and efficient way to copy all attributes of root of an hdf5 file into a python dict, or do I have to loop over it?

I did now

```
my_dict = dict(file.attrs.items())
```

Answer (score 3):

https://docs.h5py.org/en/stable/high/attr.html

`file.attr` is a dictionary like interface to these attributes.  So copying should be just like copying from one dictionary to another.  But do you really need to copy?

For a start I'd try:

```
your_dict.update(file.attr)
```

Comment: thank you for your reply. I revised my original post. How does this compare to your solution?